# PMD Review code error ocuured in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pmd

why I am getting review code error when Im gonna check my code using PMD

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V]

Answer (score 0):

in my case have installed **PMD for Eclipse 4** then started getting same error like this.

Then installed **PMD for Eclipse** package same got resolved and working fine in eclipse Neon.

PMD URL : https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/